# Auswahl besser mit "mehrere" oder "verschiedene"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Aus einer Menge von strukturell unterschiedlichen Möglichkeiten möchte ich eine Option auswählen. Dazu ein Beispiel:

> Erdbeben, ein Streik des Nahverkehrs oder eine Unachtsamkeit eines Ingenieurs können potenziell dazu führen, dass die öffentliche Wasserversorgung beeinträchtigt ist.

Wie formuliere ich am besten die Auswahl:

> **Mehrere** Gründe können die Wasserversorgung beeinträchtigen, nämlich ...

Das betont die *Vielzahl der Möglichkeiten*, die ich aber gar nicht ausdrücken will, da nur sehr selten Streiks und Erdbeben gleichzeitig auftreten.

> **Verschiedene** Gründe können die Wasserversorgung beeinträchtigen, nämlich ...

Das betont *die Unterschiedlichkeit*, worauf ich auch keinen Fokus legen möchte, da es offensichtlich ist, dass sich Streiks und Unachtsamkeiten unterscheiden.

Weitere Optionen sind *Diverse Gründe*, *Viele Gründe*, sowie *Unterschiedliche Gründe*, die aber alle letztlich auf eine der oberen Varianten verweisen.

Gibt es ein besser passendes Attribut für solche Situationen?

Comment: Worauf möchtest du denn den Fokus legen? Wenn du weder die Verschiedenheit noch die Vielzahl betonen möchtest, wäre doch vielleicht der allererste Satz (der mit *Erdbeben* beginnt) die beste Option, vielleicht sogar ohne *können dazu führen*: "Erdbeben, ein Streik des Nahverkehrs oder eine Unachtsamkeit eines Ingenieurs könn(t)en die Wasserversorgung beeinträchtigen." Das ist keine Antwort, sondern eher eine Nachfrage, ob diese Möglichkeit in Frage käme.

Answer (score 2):

Nur auf die gegebenen Möglichkeiten bezogen würde ich *Verschiedene Gründe* nehmen, es ist zwar klar, dass die Gründe verschieden sind, aber in dem Fall empfinde ich den Satz nicht so, dass auf die Verschiedenartigkeit abgehoben werden soll, sondern dass es eben eine gewisse Anzahl an Gründen gibt. Daher finde ich verschiedene durchaus nicht falsch, meinem Empfinden nach kann *verschieden* hier auch als Ausdruck für eine Anzahl größer als 1 verstanden werden.

Spontan würden mir aber noch zwei weitere Alternativen einfallen:

Wenn ein spezieller Grund (zum Beispiel der häufigste) hervorgehoben werden soll, könnte man *neben* verwenden:

> Neben der Unachtsamkeit eines Ingenieurs können auch Erdbeben oder ein
> Streik des Nahverkehrs zu einer Beeinträchtigung der öffentlichen
> Wasserversorgung führen.

Wenn kein Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit erhoben werden soll, könnte je nach Kontext auch das hier funktionieren:

> Unter mehreren denkbaren Gründen für eine Beeinträchtigung sind die
> häufigsten Gründe ein Erdbeben, ein Streik, eine Unachtsamkeit [...]

Answer (score 0):

> **Einige** Gründe können die Wasserversorgung beeinträchtigen, nämlich ...

könnte passen.

Convaldos Antwort finde ich auch gut, aber man kann auch ganz auf die fraglichen Wörter verzichten (folgende Version finde ich als Muttersprachler schöner und ist amadeusamadeus Kommentar ähnlich):

> Denkbare Gründe für eine Beeinträchtigung [der öffentlichen Wasserversorgung] sind Erdbeben, ein Streik, eine Unachtsamkeit [...]

Ich nutze übrigens oft den Duden, wenn ich nach Synonymen suche:

https://www.duden.de/synonyme/mehrere
https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verschieden_unterschiedlich_einige_manche